# Prevent event from propagating to children

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onclick

I am building a React component to be wrapped around other components that will grey-out the children and (hopefully) make them unreactive to clicks.

My approach is:

```
const TierGater: React.FC = (props) => {
  const handleTierGaterClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    console.log("outer - should be called");
    // e.stopPropagation();
    // e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={handleTierGaterClick}>
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("inner - should not be called");
        }}
      >
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TierGater;
```

I would like this to be a generic solution that allows me to wrap components arbitrarily without needing to modify the onClick of children components.

I have scanned various solutions but my understanding is that event handlers will fire from children to parents order. This is corroborated by console logs for the above example (inner called first).

I believe I can change the children to inspect the event target and abort onClick logic based on that, but this defeats the purpose of the component - it should wrap around any children without modifying the children.

Is the above possible? If yes, what changes would need to be introduced?

Side question: my event handler is typed with `React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>` - how can I make this work with both mouse and touch events?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `onClickCapture`, you can intercept the events in the capturing phase, before they've made it down to the children, and stop them from propagating:

```
<div onClickCapture={handleTierGaterClick}>
```

```
const handleTierGaterClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
};
```

To be more UI-friendly, a faded background and perhaps `pointer-events: none` would be good too.

Comment: Thank you - this works great as far as I can see. Clarifying questions: 1. Are both stopPropagation and preventDefault needed? If yes, what is the role of each in the context of onClickCapture? 2. WIll this work with both touch events and mouse click events? 3. When placed over a component that reacts with a short animation upon click, I can still see that animation but not the effect of the click - what do you think could be a possible explanation here?

Comment: Yes, both look necessary. `preventDefault` stops default actions from occurring (like the submission of a `<form>`, or the navigating to an `<a>`), the other one prevents descendant event listeners from triggering.

Comment: I think touch events trigger the `click` event. If they don't, you can listen for them as well and do the same thing. Regarding the animation, perhaps it's listening to some other event, like `mouseover` or something - it sounds curious, but I'd have to see the component to know for sure.